# SwfUpload Fallback for clients without Flash

Tags: flash, swfupload, fallback

Im currently using the SwfUpload (v2.2.0.1) on my asp.net web application with absolutely no issues.

What I would like to do is provide a fall back to a normal  upload when the user/client does not have flash installed.
I can imagine this could be done with something like jquery replace or similar with the use of a flash detection script.

I do not need to provide a fall back if the user/client does not have javascript.

How would I go about writing this type of fall back or does anyone have any working examples of a swfupload fall back?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the best approach is to use Flash detection as recommended by adobe here
[Adobe Flash Detection](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/fp8_detection.html) or this [similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159261/cross-browser-flash-detection-in-javascript)

Once the test is complete we could show / hide a div or input based on the results.

**Something like this (jQuery / JS):**

```
var swfu;

if (browserHasFlash() == false) {
   $("#flashUpload").hide();
   $("#regularUpload").show();
}
else {
    //Init SWF Upload
    swfu = new SWFUpload({
        upload_url : "http://www.swfupload.org/upload.php",
        flash_url : "http://www.swfupload.org/swfupload.swf",
        file_size_limit : "20 MB"
    });
}
```