# JavaScript copy text to clipboard

Tags: javascript, clipboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy selected text to the clipboard WITHOUT using flash - must be cross-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300213/copy-selected-text-to-the-clipboard-without-using-flash-must-be-cross-browser)

This one has kept me going for a long time. How would I copy text to the clipboard? Here is my code:

```
<body>
    <textarea name="text" rows="5" cols="20" wrap="hard" onblur="CopyToClipboard()">Enter text here and it will be copied to the clipboard!</textarea>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function CopyToClipboard() {
    //O_O Confused... what do I do...
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Derek I think that's a typo.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is one way you can do it...

```
<body>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="20" wrap="hard" onblur="CopyToClipboard(this)"></textarea>
</body>

<script language="JavaScript">
function CopyToClipboard(text) {
    Copied = text.createTextRange();
    Copied.execCommand("Copy");
}
</script>
```

This only works with IE 4 and above. When you run it, a dialog may come up asking you whether or not "you want this website to have access to your clipboard". Click yes if it does. Whatever text the user entered into the box will be copied to the clipboard.

Comment: What about the other browsers?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: text.createTextRange is not a function. (Chrome 46)

Comment: What about support for other browsers? (just like @Uday A. Navapara asked)