# How to use JavaScript to copy the text in a textarea to clipboard in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a textarea tag and have a button. What I want is when I click the button, the text in that textarea will be copied into my clipboard.

I am using this in a Chrome Extension.

Thanks for any kind of help!

Answer (score -3):

To [copy text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218061/javascript-copy-text-to-clipboard)...

```
function CopyToClipboard(text) {
    Copied = text.createTextRange();
    Copied.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

To [get the text](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_textarea_value.asp)...

```
textareaObject.value="text"
```