# execCommand not working in javascript jQuery to copy text to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, range

i'm trying to copy a text to the clipboard. But've already shown the text as selected in the modal window where it appears after an ajax call.The code is the following:

```
jQuery.fn.selectText = function(){
var doc = document
    , element = this[0]
    , range, selection
;
if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(element);
    range.select();
} else if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();        
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(element);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
}
```

so after `range = document.createRange();` i tryied inserting `range.execCommand('copy');` cause i've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218061/javascript-copy-text-to-clipboard) tutorial about it but it doesn't mention any problem with this command. The error i'm getting is the following:

```
TypeError: range.execCommand is not a function
```

[This is a mozilla tutorial about execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2Fdocument.execCommand#Executing_Commands).

Comment: `execCommand` is a member of `document`.

Comment: Marcell is correct, "...the document object exposes the execCommand method which allows one to run commands to manipulate the contents of the editable region."

Comment: So how can i apply the "copy" command to a specific text in javascript?

Comment: Actually IE's `TextRange` object, roughly equivalent to the DOM Range implemented in other browsers, has an `execCommand()` method, but it isn't usually useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A range doesn't have an `execCommand` function, the `execCommand` function belongs to the `document` object.

Taken from the same tutorial:

> When an HTML document has been switched to designMode, the document
>   object exposes the execCommand method which allows one to run commands
>   to manipulate the contents of the editable region. Most commands
>   affect the document's selection (bold, italics, etc), while others
>   insert new elements (adding a link) or affect an entire line
>   (indenting). When using contentEditable, calling execCommand will
>   affect the currently active editable element.