# Jquery how to copy text to clipboard when we are click on button?

Tags: jquery, copy, clipboard

Good day.

We have code:

```
<div id="test" style="display:none">text for test copy</div>
<button id="button">copy</button>
```

For get text in div we use jquery:

```
$("#button").on("click",function(){
 var text = $("#test").html();
 alert(text);
});
```

But i dont know how copy text to clipboard...

*Tell me please how copy text (on jquery code it will be `text`) to clipboard ?*

*P.S.: preferably without flash.*

Comment: **[Clipboard Plugin](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-copy-clipboard-4-options/#.UFbo1YriYz0)**. Search for more on google.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218061/javascript-copy-text-to-clipboard as well

Comment: refer this link:
http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/

Comment: @shaunakde i know it, if i understand this plugin work with flash, i would like work without flash, only on jquery, becouse not all platforms use flash(for example in iphone flash not work)

Comment: It is possible in IE without `flash` for all others you'll need `flash`. Possibly only one great thing in IE :).

Comment: @VedantTerkar very bad(-

Answer (score 0):

In `IE` the browser provide default object to work with clipboard. You can find the more information regarding how to use `window.clipBoardData` in the below link.

[window.clipBoardData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms535220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

In `FireFox` they have interface component to do this. Please refer the below link.

[Using the Clipboard in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_the_Clipboard)