# Copy url title to clipboard

Tags: jquery, url, clipboard

Sometime ago, I made a list of links that have long titles. The original script let me push those link titles into a div when clicked on. Since then, the page has changed and I've lost that script. What would be better though, is if I could use those same links, but simply copy the link title (i.e. title="") to the clipboard. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, I saw that and forgot to mention that I'd like a non-flash option. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300213/copy-selected-text-to-the-clipboard-without-using-flash-must-be-cross-browser