# how can i copy text from textbox to clipboard using jquery/javascript/html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create a copy to clipboard button on a website. However, all the method I found involved a small Flash. Is there a way to create the copy to clipboard button without using Flash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy text to the client's clipboard using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539641/copy-text-to-the-clients-clipboard-using-jquery)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy selected text to the clipboard WITHOUT using flash - must be cross-browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300213/copy-selected-text-to-the-clipboard-without-using-flash-must-be-cross-browser)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy to clipboard without Flash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355300/copy-to-clipboard-without-flash)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  Im struggling to get anything to work without flash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some jQuery plugins like:

http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/clipboard

Comment: this plugin use flash

Comment: the steamdev.com link is broken.