# ZK Framework Integration with copy to Clipboard

Tags: jquery, zk

I am looking how we can integrate copy to clipboard feature of **Jquery**(Browser Compatible)  with **ZK Framwork**

Answer (score 0):

As you're trying to perform an operation on the user's box, you will need to be on the client side to do this. That is to say, ZK's client/server syncing tricks aren't going to help here. You could still kick off this operation from the server, but once you have the text you want to put in the user's clipboard you'll need to send it to the client first.

All that said, there are plenty of questions here on StackOverflow dealing with copying something to the user's clipboard from JavaScript. You'll notice a number of the answers suggest using Flash instead as there are some security concerns on some browsers regarding a website automatically affecting the user's clipboard.

Relevant questions with answers:
[How to copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212)
[Copy text to the client's clipboard using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539641)
[Copy to clipboard without Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355300)
[Copy selected text to the clipboard WITHOUT using flash - must be cross-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300213)