# How to copy to clipbord content of textarea using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

Hi  I am using codemirror for textarea. I want to copy conent of textarea to clipbord, i want to javascript or jquery scipt support for all major browser.

```
<textarea name="code" id="text_1" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<script>
$("#text_1").click(function(){

    // required code for copy text in  clipbord 
});
```

Comment: Flash plugin can do it.

Comment: how to use flash plugin?

Comment: if the text is selected, copying is not much more work than clicking

Comment: Javascript cannot do this across browsers. You must use Flash. Refer to this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300213/copy-selected-text-to-the-clipboard-without-using-flash-must-be-cross-browser

Comment: Goog: `copy to clipboard :stackoverflow`

Comment: [ZeroClipboard](http://zeroclipboard.org/#demo)

Comment: works on IE window.clipboardData.setData("Text", "your clipboard");