# JavaScript to copy text

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to create a javascript to copy text to clipboard and display an alert coupon copied and when user close it or clicks ok it should visit another website in new page.

basically i am using wordpress's siteorigin pagebuilder widget in which i can only provide the javascripct name as "script.js".

so what I want is when that script runs it takes the button id and copy its text to clipboard and then shows a error message and tells code copied and when user cancels the alert or click ok then it should open a link.

Comment: You need to do some little searches before asking such question, as it has already been posted like 5x times in SO. Check this one for example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300213/copy-selected-text-to-the-clipboard-without-using-flash-must-be-cross-browser

Answer (score 0):

Currently, almost all browsers have prohibited access to the clipboard by javascript.

So, whatever you try here will fail due to browser restrictions. There are settings modifications which re-grant access to the clipboard, but they are not practicable in an end user scenario.

There are certain solutions around which are either based on a java plugin or a small flash app. The latter is the most stable and useful, can be found here:http://zeroclipboard.org/

Comment: thank you. ok then is there any script to change button's text and then after 15 sec it shows the alert to go to other site

Comment: You may change whatever is in the dom, but you can't copy it to the clipboard of the user.

Comment: Sorry but I am beginner about this actually i am using wordpress can you share the script please and also what should i write in onClick="".