# Select text and autocopy whithout ctr+c

Tags: javascript, php

I need an js or php script who can help me to "s**elect text and autocopy**" without press ctrl + c, just select and copy in my **html table columns page**, could I do that?

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy selected text to the clipboard WITHOUT using flash - must be cross-browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300213/copy-selected-text-to-the-clipboard-without-using-flash-must-be-cross-browser)

Comment: You can't reliably do this in all browsers yet. There's also absolutely no way to do this on iPads/iPhones.

Comment: use `document.execCommand('copy')`. this will copy current selected text

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this:

https://clipboardjs.com/

It is a javascript library that does ecactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I need just while selecting the text, this selection can copy my text without using an **Submit Button / or copy button**.

Thank you