# How can I detect browser support of Flash in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, detect

This my HTML code but if the browser does not support Flash then I want to replace the image in the Flash part

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      if (typeof navigator.plugins['Shockwave Flash'] !== 'undefined') {
        alert('support');
      } else {
        alert('not support');
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/159261/508702

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use one of the Flash Detection JavaScript libraries out there. [This one](http://www.featureblend.com/javascript-flash-detection-library.html) works well.