# How to set a auto website switchover for mobile user? Flash is not supported on most mobile browser

Tags: android, html, flash, mobile, web

I have a website running flash that works great on desktop but its not support on Android browser. How do I set up an auto switchover? When the site detects its a mobile user, display  a static web site instead of dynamic flash site?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159261/cross-browser-flash-detection-in-javascript once you know if your browser is capable or not you can load the appropriate content

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to include Flash in the HTML page (its a small JavaScript library). It includes facility to display alternative (html) content if Flash Player not detected.

So you just add the home page of your static site as the alternative content of the Flash display; and user will see Flash site if they have Flash installed, or static site if they dont.

This way you are doing a more general switchover - can device play Flash? rather than is this a mobile device?