# How can I check lower version of flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

How can I check whether browse has lower version of flash or not through javascript or jquery? I am able to detect whether Flash is installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the comments of [Cross Browser Flash Detection in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159261/cross-browser-flash-detection-in-javascript) is a small javascript code line that reads also the version.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("1")) //Check your browser have flash or not
{
    alert("You have flash!");
}
else
{
    alert("You do not flash :-(");
}

if(swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion(" 11.7.700.169 "))//Check latest flash or not
{
    alert("You have the minimum required flash version (or newer)");
}
else
{
    alert("You do not have the minimum required flash version");
}
```