# Hide Flash content from browsers without it

Tags: javascript, html, flash

The question is very simple, I hope the solution too.

I have a flash player that I use for streaming sound via rtmp. When I visit the website with a browser that doesn't support flash I get an ugly grey square. So I was thinking it would be great if I could hide that div if flash is not enabled, or if the browser doesn't support it. Pretty much the same way one can hide stuff using media-query for different screen sizes.

Is that possible? And if so..how?

Thank you!

Comment: [Cross Browser Flash Detection in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159261/cross-browser-flash-detection-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) and check if the browser has flash.

```
if(!swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("1"))
{
    var flashObjects = document.getElementsByTagName("object");
    for(var i=0;i<flashObjects.length;i++)
    {
        flashObjects[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```