# How to detect an Operating System

Tags: html, iphone, ipad, flash, operating-system

I am in the process of trying to rewrite my website, and I have limited experience in HTML/CSS/Javascript. It is a photography website using galleries. I am wanting to make the default view to be using Flash, but I know that iPad/iPhone etc do not support Flash. I am looking for a way to determine what the OS is so I can direct the iWhatevers (and others if there are any), to a purely HTML site, and the non-iWhatevers to the Flash site. 
I presume it would be done in the Heading part of the HTML, but what script would I use to do this?
Thank you in advance...

Comment: Purely a suggestion, but why maintain two versions?  If you want to support everyone, just develop a non-flash site that works for everyone.

Comment: Given the future of Flash and the rise of HTML5 you might do better to implement an HTML5 solution and fall back to Flash for the older browsers.

Comment: ... and if you need to test for Flash, detect it directly, not the operating system. [Cross Browser Flash Detection in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/159261)

Answer (score -1):

That sounds like a lot of extra work to create to maintain a Flash and a regular HTML site when a properly done HTML5 site can kill all the browsers with one stone. Consider a CMS like WordPress if you are not comfortable with a lot of coding.

However, if you want to go the route you mentioned, this thread will show you how: [Detect if device is iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios)