# Detecting browser to determine display flash or html

Tags: html, css, flash

I have a question regarding displaying different content on different web browsing device.  I know with CSS i can display different style sheet according to browser width size.  But the challenge I have now is Flash content, I am setting up a Flash content for my company website and as we all know flash isn't supported in mobile device.  To resolve this I thought about making a simple HTML version of the website for mobile devices.  However, what can I use to determine when to load the flash or when to load the html?  For example if I were to visit the site through my desktop the FLASH website will load and if i were to use my phone to visit the site, the HTML website will load. I am pretty new into web designing so any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks alot in advance

Comment: I'd just always go with HTML/CSS/JS; flash is dead. CSS3 is capable of many things now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross Browser Flash Detection in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159261/cross-browser-flash-detection-in-javascript)

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question but is HTML/CSS/JS able to create effects that can be created in flash?  I do however, doesn't need fancy effects, perhaps just page transition, gallery effect etc.

Answer (score 0):

theoretically you could do this with media queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
   .flash{
     display: none;
   }

   .html-content{
     //css styles for html mobile site
   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px){
   .flash{
      //styles for flash container
   }

   .html-content{
      display: none;
   }
}
```

But Josh C is right, you should avoid Flash these days and use CSS3 or JS

Comment: Thx jmore for the advice and the snippet, will take a look at it now