# How to findout the client machine has installed flash player using javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash

[Cross Browser Flash Detection in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159261/cross-browser-flash-detection-in-javascript/5159190#comment24828865_12902290)

I have use the flash_detect.js as mentioned in above link. It works fine in IE8 and Chrome 29. But its not working in FF 25.

Can anyone please me here to resolve this issue?

else

suggest if any other better ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help you:

Detect Flash with JavaScript

http://www.blangdon.com/writing/about/detect-flash-with-javascript/

Or

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/plugindetect.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Note that a 32 bit Firefox version will require 32 bit versions of plugins, so make sure that you have the correct version.

Firefox also finds the Flash plugin for me as installed by the Flash installer rpm file

/usr/lib/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so
As an alternative you can install the Flash plugin (place a symlink) in your home directory /home//.mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so

You can try to delete the pluginreg.dat file in the Firefox Profile Folder and maybe addons.sqlite as well to reset the plugin registry databases.

See Re-initializing the plugins database:

https://support.mozilla.org/kb/troubleshoot-issues-with-plugins-fix-problems

OR just see this..

[Cross Browser Flash Detection in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159261/cross-browser-flash-detection-in-javascript?lq=1)

Comment: I am already tried with "Cross Browser Flash Detection in Javascript" link. My issue here is, i am getting using this code "navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-shockwave-flash"]" this returns an object which helps to identity the flash has installed or not. But issue is, it works with Chrome 29 and IE 8. But undefined returned with Firefox 30.

Answer (score 0):

I need to install flash played in FF's extension then only it able to identify whether flash player is installed or not.