# how to display cusom content when adobe flash player is not active?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, embedded-flashplayer, flashplayer-debug

how to display custom content when adobe flash player is not active. also when user click on custom content than adobe flash player will automatically enable OR show window for allow and block.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4565606/552116

Comment: Its only for detect adobe flash player is active or not. this is not useful for me.